# Synchronizing text and audio. Is there a NLP/speech-to-text library to do this?

Tags: nlp, speech-recognition, pattern-recognition

I would like to synchronize a spoken recording against a known text.  Is there a speech-to-text / natural language processing library that would facilitate this?  I imagine I'd want to detect word boundaries and compute candidate matches from a dictionary.  Most of the questions I've found on SO concern written language.

Desired, but not required:

- Open Source
- Compatible with American English out-of-the-box
- Cross-platform
- Thoroughly documented

Edit: I realize this is a very broad, even naive, question, so thanks in advance for your guidance.

What I've found so far:

- [OpenEars](http://www.politepix.com/openears/) (iOS Sphinx/Flite wrapper)

Comment: I'm looking to do the same thing, Sphinx seems overly large and erratically documented.  Wondering what you ended up with and if you are aware of anything more up to date -- I see this question goes back 2 years so things must have changed since then?

Comment: I moved on from the project before learning enough to contribute any more to the discussion.

Comment: For the record: I maintain the Python/C forced aligner aeneas: https://github.com/readbeyond/aeneas/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Forced Alignment**

It sounds like you want to do **[forced alignment](http://www.isip.piconepress.com/projects/speech/software/tutorials/production/fundamentals/v1.0/section_04/s04_04_p01.html)** between your audio and the known text.

Pretty much all research/industry grade speech recognition systems will be able to do this, since forced alignment is an important part of training a recognition system on data that doesn't have [phone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoneme) level alignments between the audio and the transcript.

**Alignment CMUSphinx**

The [Sphinx4-1.0 beta 5 release](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2010/09/sphinx4-1-0-beta-4-released-2/) of CMU's open source speech recognition system now includes a demo on how to do alignment between a transcript and long speech recordings.

Comment: This Sphinx is a pretty useful looking library, but the instructions on how to use on iPhone seem quite dated (iOS 3?) and comments suggest that it isn't easy to implement on iOS4.  I wonder if there is more up to date information on this available?