# Synchronization between Audio & Text for iPhone/iPad SDK

Tags: iphone

Is there any way to sync audio with text. I have to highlight text word by word for audio file. Text is shown in HTML pages & audioPlay function is implmented in Objective C.

Comment: This may be a dupe of my own question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072020/synchronizing-text-and-audio-is-there-a-nlp-speech-to-text-library-to-do-this

Answer (score 1):

I know in flash you would use que points. Maybe iphone as a similar api? Failing that you could do it really easy on the timeline in flash and then package the swf for iphone.

Comment: Interesting thought, I didn't know you could package an swf for iphone (which doesn't support flash?).  I don't suppose you can provide a link on how to do this?

Comment: As far as I remember it's an export feature in flash cs5 /air . http://www.adobe.com/products/air.html. I was going to use it but I opted to write the app natively for performance reasons.